# Cookie is not set properly

Tags: javascript, cookies

newbie here.
Trying to create a cookie like this

```
    function setCook()
{
    var name=prompt("enter your name");
    document.cookie=name;
    var mycookie = document.cookie,
    fixed_cookie = decodeURIComponent(mycookie);

}
function getCookie()
{

    var mycookie = fixed_cookie;
    document.write(mycookie);
}

setCook();
getCookie();
```

But somehow the document is blank.
**Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.**

Comment: You placed a `,`, instead of a `;` in the `var mycookie = document.cookie,` line. Placing the `;` will make it an implicit global, but that's not so good, it'd be better if you declared `fixed_cookie` outside of both functions, or if you did: `window.fixed_cookie`.  Also, `document.cookie` returns all of the cookies related to the document, I don't know if you want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Try the following:

```
function setCook()
{
    var name=prompt("enter your name");
    document.cookie="mycookie="+name+"; path=\";
}
```

**Explanation**

A document can actually have multiple cookies, so cookies are given names.

To set a cookie named "mycookie", you would do this:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=some value";
```

You can also set multiple cookies at once like this:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie1=value1; mycookie2=value2; mycookie3=value3";
```

Also, you should note that document.cookie is not just a standard property, but rather a getter and setter. To illustrate this:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=this is mine";
document.cookie = "yourcookie=this is yours";

// alert is: mycookie=this is mine; yourcookie=this is yours
window.alert(document.cookie);
```

Hopefully this should get you started.
Please look at [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223).

Comment: jfriend00 is right on point that accessing document.cookie gives all the cookies for the document.  You would need to parse the string to extract the value for a single cookie.  This is why frameworks such as jQuery provide utility functions to work with cookies that abstract these details away.

Comment: EDIT: I missed the `,`.  Therefore my comment below is moot.  As a result of the `,`, `fixed_cookie` is declared as a local variable after all!  This is because multiple variables can be declared in one statement (e.g. `var var1="a", var2="b", var3="c";`). My original comment follows: By the way, in response to @jfriend00, fixed_cookie is not a local variable! Local variables are usually declared var myvariable = "some value"; however, when a variable is declared without the word var, it implicitly becomes a property of the window object, and all properties of window are global.